# PHP Query a third table in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables. One for my restaurants (cc_restaurants), one for the working hours of the restaurants (cc_workhours) and a third one for a kind of cuisine in the restaurant(cc_cuisines)
As you can see below I have assigned to my restaurants a working hour based on a common column. Here is working because each row in cc_workinghours is assigned to only one restaurant:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants r 
    JOIN cc_workhours w ON r.rest_id = w.time_asoc  
    WHERE r.rest_loc='hk'
";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        //some code
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

But now I need to query a third table (cc_cuisines)... In `cc_restaurants` I have a column called `rest_cuisine` (a brief of this data you can see it in the `explode` function)... so after that I want to query in the third table (cc_cuisines) all the cuisines relates with the codes in the column `rest_cuisine` in the restaurants table... this is why I write the code below....

```
$cuisines = implode('","' , explode('/','hk-01/hk-06'));
$sql_cuisine = 'SELECT * FROM cc_cuisines WHERE cuisine_asoc IN ("'. $cuisines .'")';
$result_cuisine = $conn->query($sql_cuisine);
while( $row2 = $result_cuisine->fetch()) {
    echo $row2['cuisine_name'];
}
```

Finally I need to do the second loop, inside the first one and assign the respective cuisines to the respective restaurant...

Any idea about how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you understand the difference between a database and a table.

Comment: whats the Problem? your ressource-variables have different names, your result-variables have different names, should be no Problem (i assume you work with one database only and you think of different tables). please Show us, what your real Problem is

Comment: please be Aware of, that you could habe multiple second-query-resuls for one first-query-result

Comment: gotta love the N+1 approach!

Comment: what do you mean by " QUERY A THIRD DATABASE HERE " ?

Comment: Sorry is not database the word, is table... was a long day at work... i need to put the second loop inside the first one

Comment: Sounds like a good old `ctrl + c` and `ctrl + v` will do the trick. Have you tried it?

Comment: @TomasLucena Please, add information to your question about tables structure and what data do you want to retrieve from them.

Comment: please take a look to see if the new edit is more useful

Comment: Forget about the PHP. Delete it. Just focus on the SQL code for now. Consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @TomasLucena Is this a system you are building from scratch? If so, you should store restaraunt--cuisine relationships in a separate table, because it is many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @TomasLucena Then, you can query all cuisines names for the restaraunt comma-separated or likewise with `GROUP_CONCAT`, without PHP loops.

Comment: thanks mate, will read about that

Answer (score 1):

Most DB engines will let you execute multiple queries! If, for some reason, you can't, then: run the first queries; cache the rows in an array; and then loop through that to run the third query.

```
<?php
    $sql = "
        SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants r 
        JOIN cc_workhours w ON r.rest_id = w.time_asoc  
        WHERE r.rest_loc='hk'
    ";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

    $aAllRows = array();    /*****   Create Array */
    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $aAllRows[] = $row;  /**** Cache row in array */
        }
    }
    foreach ($aAllRows as $row){    /****** Loop through array */
        //QUERY A THIRD TABLE HERE
        $cuisines = implode('","' , explode('/','hk-01/hk-06'));
        $sql_cuisine = 'SELECT * FROM cc_cuisines WHERE cuisine_asoc IN ("'. $cuisines .'")';
        $result_cuisine = $conn->query($sql_cuisine);
        while( $row2 = $result_cuisine->fetch()) {
            echo $row2['cuisine_name'];
        }

        echo RESULT FIRST QUERY. '/'. RESULT SECOND QUERY
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

As several comments have said, there's a difference between a *table* and a *database*. I think this has caused some confusion.

Comment: hey thanks, I can not test it right now but at least I can I will let you know